# How can i have Multiple IF Statements with multiple result value in BQ?

Tags: sql, if-statement, google-bigquery, split, case

I have a BQ question and appreciate your help.

I have the following field: **category**

Which contains different values. photo attached

I need to unnest that and capture the value inside and it seems a complicated task for me.

The logic is that if the length of category tag is **0** (which i assume something like first row of picture attached and this  `ARRAY_LENGTH(SPLIT(category_tags, '|')) = 0`   then call it as parent='archaeology';

If the length is   **`ARRAY_LENGTH(SPLIT(category_tags, '|')) = 1`**   ( like the second row) then the first character would be **child** and the second one would be **parent** `( child='geology', parent='planet earth')`.

If the length is like 3rd row then it should be `(grandchild='alligator' would be 0 offset , parent='Animals' which is the 1 offset, child='reptiles' which is 2 offset)`.

And finally if the length is like 7 row, with 4 values, it should be like `(greatgrandchild='orcas' which is 0 offset, parent='Animals' which is the 1 offset, child='marrine mammal' which is 2 offset, grandchild='dolphines' would be 3 offset)`.

**In a simplest explanation :

```
1 word  = parent
and 12 = child/parent
and 123 = grandchild/parent/child
and 1234 = greatgrandchild/parent/child/grandchild.**
```

So, i need this to be recorded as **category_type** which would be (parent/child/grandchild/greatgrandchild) and  **Category_name** which could contains the values. Something like this: picture attached.

Can anyone help with the BQ code for this? thanks in advance.

[image: category]
[image: desiredoutput]

I have tried the query which was mentioned in the comment and this is the result: it is not picking up any other category_type:
[image: test of a test query which was shared in the comments]

Answer (score 0):

Consider below approach (BigQuery Standard SQL)

```
SELECT SPLIT(category_tag, '/')[OFFSET(0)] category_name, 
  ['', 'Parent', 'Child', 'Grandchild', 'Greatgrandchild'][OFFSET(ARRAY_LENGTH(SPLIT(category_tag, '/')))] AS category_type,
  '/' || REGEXP_REPLACE(category_tag, r'^([^/]+)(/)(.*)', r'\3\2\1') AS category 
FROM your_table
```

if applied to sample data as in your question

```
WITH your_table AS (
  SELECT 'archeology' category_tag UNION ALL
  SELECT 'geology/planet earth' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'the moon/space/astronomy' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'orcas/animals/marine mammals/dolphins' 
)
```

output is

[image]

If you use `|` as a separator - use below instead

```
SELECT SPLIT(category_tag,'|')[OFFSET(0)] category_name, 
  ['', 'Parent', 'Child', 'Grandchild', 'Greatgrandchild'][OFFSET(ARRAY_LENGTH(SPLIT(category_tag, '|')))] AS category_type,
  '/' || REGEXP_REPLACE(REPLACE(category_tag, '|', '/'), r'^([^/]+)(/)(.*)', r'\3\2\1') AS category 
FROM your_table
```

Comment: Thanks so much for this. But when i apply it, it does not pick up the child/grandchild, and greatgrandchild. It only picks up the parents. I can add the screenshot of the output in this page

Comment: have you tried with sample data in my answer? are you using `/` or`|` in your real data?

Comment: Yes it works on the sample data but in a real data i am using `|`. I can see that why it was confusing, category_tag has `|` as a seperator. I added the screen shot of the output and category_tag is there also.

Comment: see update. very minor.

Comment: I see this error: `Array index 5 is out of bounds (overflow)` . which i guess that is because there might be some category_tags that have 5 words or maybe more which i was not aware of. Is there any way of ignoring the rest values? after 4th word?

Comment: sure. as of now you have really good starting point that fully answers your original question, so try something on your own and if still problem - post new specific question and I will be happy to help further. with this question - I am done :o)

Comment: Thanks sure. very much appriciate it

Comment: This is the link to my new question :D https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76683128/how-do-i-ignore-any-words-after-the-4th-word-in-string-which-is-seperated-by  and thanks in advance

Comment: i feel like both your questions are fully answered now!