# How do I ignore any words after the 4th word in string which is seperated by '|'?

Tags: google-bigquery, split

I would appriciate it if anyone can help.

It is the follow up of my previous question in here: [How can i have Multiple IF Statements with multiple result value in BQ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76681531/how-can-i-have-multiple-if-statements-with-multiple-result-value-in-bq/76681963#76681963)

This is working okay but only if my category_tags has 4 words.

How can I ignore the rest values? any thing after 4th word?

something like category_tags= animals|land-mammals|cats|domestic-cats|blackcat|cutecat

It should ignore anything after domestic-cats

this is the qode which works so far:

```
SELECT SPLIT(category_tag,'|')[OFFSET(0)] category_name, 
  ['', 'Parent', 'Child', 'Grandchild', 'Greatgrandchild'][OFFSET(ARRAY_LENGTH(SPLIT(category_tag, '|')))] AS category_type,
  '/' || REGEXP_REPLACE(REPLACE(category_tag, '|', '/'), r'^([^/]+)(/)(.*)', r'\3\2\1') AS category 
FROM your_table
```

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope you can incorporate below into solution for your previous question

```
SELECT 
  (SELECT STRING_AGG(tag, '|' ORDER BY OFFSET) 
    FROM UNNEST(SPLIT(category_tag, '|')) tag WITH OFFSET
    WHERE OFFSET < 4
  ) AS category_tag
FROM your_table
```

if applied to sample data

```
WITH your_table AS (
  SELECT 'archeology' category_tag UNION ALL
  SELECT 'geology|planet earth' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'the moon|space|astronomy' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'orcas|animals|marine mammals|dolphins' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'animals|land-mammals|cats|domestic-cats|blackcat|cutecat'
)
```

output is

[image]